# Keep fixed the div only while scrolling and depends on the parent div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to fixed the left and right div while only scrolling. It only fixed while scrolling and depends upon the parent div. I want to do some [like this](http://tastykhana.in/bangalore/bellandur-cinemax/domino-s-pizza-8457#).
On that website, category div on left side, is fixed while scrolling and it fixed only within the parent div. Not exceed on the div.

Here my [sample plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/6AV8dwDtpadWEHmz7Rnh/preview). I want to do same thing in my website too fixed the both left and right div. 
Is it possible to done by `angularjs` instead of `jquery`?

can anyone help for me?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b43hj/ this link might help you

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it can be done using angularjs as i've not really looked into it but it can easily be done using

var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;       // get initial position of the element

$(window).scroll(function() {                  // assign scroll event listener

```
var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position

if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {           // apply position: fixed if you
    $('.fixme').css({                      // scroll to that element or below it
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0',
        left: '0'
    });
} else {                                   // apply position: static
    $('.fixme').css({                      // if you scroll above it
        position: 'static'
    });
}
```

});

Comment: but if the `position` has been fixed, div height and width can be changed. without of height, width changes is it possible.

Comment: @Aniruth Sorry can you explain a little clearer what you mean and I will try and help you make it.

Comment: check my plunkr again

Comment: Ohh i see what you mean, because of the fixed position it doesn't dynamically change

Comment: Because you need the position to be fixed to make it stay at the top of the page, the only way that I can think of to make the site adjust is to create a few media queries changing the width and location of the div at different page widths, sorry I couldn't offer more help.